# How to use references to another workbooks when using VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to ask you for your help with my code. I am trying to get the value from another workbook and put it in the current workbook through VLOOKUP. I want to use the reference to a workbook and not the exact name because the name of the search workbook will change. Here's the code:

```
Sub Thu_submission_ships()
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 2, "Open last week's EMEA GA Backlog YYYY-MM-DD submission")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen

    Set wb_blog = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht_blog = wb_blog.Sheets("Backlog")

    Columns("X:X").NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveSheet.Range("X2:Z" & LastRow_blog).Name = "blog"
    wb_blog.Save

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 1, "Open today's GA ships")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen

    Sheets("Ships").Select

    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("X:X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("X2:X" & LastRow2).Formula = "=F2&L2"
    Range("X2:X" & LastRow2).Copy: Range("X2:X" & LastRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("X2").Select
    Columns("X:X").NumberFormat = "@"

    Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X2, sht_blog!blog, 2, False)"

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What works? Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could build your formula in string variable:

```
sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(X2,'[" & sht_blog.parent.name &"]" & sht_blog.name &"'!blog, 2,0)"
```

and then simply:

```
Range("Y2").Formula = sFormula
```

Comment: @MercinSzaleniec thank you very much! works great. I just have one issue with it. in one vlookup it gives me values correctly, but the second one doesn't, it gives me #REF!. i have the same code, just instead of 2 i want value from 3rd column. Can you see where the problem could be?

Comment: what you can in in formula bar when clicking on the cell with #REF!?

Comment: it was exactly the same as the first one. here's the code i got:
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BG" & LastRow2).AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:="#N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X2,'[" & sht_ships.Parent.Name & "]" & sht_ships.Name & "'!ships, 2,0)"
    Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X2,'[" & sht_ships.Parent.Name & "]" & sht_ships.Name & "'!ships, 3,0)"
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Comment: I cannot decode script in comment. What you get in the cell after running the macro? BTW, are you sure that named range "ships" is at least three columns wide?

Comment: ah, you're right! i found out that i made one minor change in the file and it made that! thanks a lot for your help, it works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your post is a bit confusing, but see the code below for the concept as well as comments explaining.

```
Option Explicit

Sub VlookupExample()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant

    'grabs workbook
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 1, "Open today's GA ships")
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileToOpen

    'FileToOpen now stores the workbook full path name
    'strip out only workbook name
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Mid(FileToOpen, InStrRev(FileToOpen, "\") + 1, 255)

    'Now use in vlookup (same way you would if entered manually in cell.
    Range("Y2").Formula = "=vlookup(X2," & FileName & "!blog,2,False)"

End Sub
```